# How to stop getting NIL from if statement in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Sorry to ask this question, but I was learning optional parameters in LISP
Hence I created a function called "calculate-bill" which will take two parameters :

- amount (this is the required parameter)
- discount (this is an optional parameter)

So as you can guess if the discount is passed to the function it will cut its value from the amount else just print the amount.

Code :

```
(defun calculate-bill (amount &optional discount)
  (if (null discount)
    (format t "Total bill is ~d." amount))
  (if discount
    (format t "Total bill is ~d." (- amount discount))))

(write (calculate-bill 200 50))
(terpri)
(write (calculate-bill 200))
```

Here I had added null condition in if blocks.

I want my expected output to be :

```
Total bill is 150.
Total bill is 200.
```

But the current output is :

```
Total bill is 150.NIL
Total bill is 200.NIL
```

How can I avoid that "NIL" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing double output. You call FORMAT and WRITE.

Now you need to find out whether you really want to do double output and, if not, which function to keep and which not.

Answer (score 2):

The function `calculate-bill` prints out the message "Total amount is...", but this is just a *side effect*. The **value** returned by the function is, when there is no explicit `return <value>`, the value of the last executed function, which in this case is `format`, and the value of `format` is always nil when the output stream is T. So what the write function does is to print the value returned by `calculate-bill` which is nil. If you want `calculate-bill` to return the string then change the output stream of format to nil:

```
(format nil "Total bill is ~d." amount)
```

This creates a string which is not printed until you pass it to an output function like e.g. `write`.

As an extra suggestion, the function `if` can take three parameters: the test, the code to execute when the test is t, and the code to execute when the test is nil. So, in your case, it is far better to write:

```
(if (null discount)
    (format t "Total bill is ~d." amount)
    (format t "Total bill is ~d." (- amount discount)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameter admit a default value, you could for example have a default discount of zero.

```
(defun calculate-bill (amount &optional (discount 0))
  (check-type discount real)
  (- amount discount))
```

Answer (score 1):

Choose default for discount as `0` then you save the `null` testing.

Further, I would `format` to `nil` to just return the strings.

```
(defun calculate-bill (amount &optional (discount 0))
  (format nil "Total bill is ~d." (- amount discount)))
```

`write` prints and returns. Only printing you achieve by `(format t "~a" x)`.

```
(progn 
  (format t "~a" (calculate-bill 200 50)) 
  (terpri) 
  (format t "~a" (calculate-bill 200)))
```

Alternatively you can include `"~%"` into `format` string instead using `(terpri)`.

```
(progn 
  (format t "~a~%" (calculate-bill 200 50)) 
  (format t "~a~%" (calculate-bill 200)))
```

I would optionally let display the result but return the string.

```
(defun calculate-bill (amount &key (discount 0) (verbosep nil))
  (let* ((result (- amount discount))
        (res (format nil "Total bill is ~d." result)))
    (if verbosep
      (format t "~a~%" res))
    res))
```

Then set `:verbosep t` if you want the output visible in the terminal.

```
(calculate-bill 200 :discount 50 :verbosep t)
(calculate-bill 200 :verbosep t)
```